# Allow users to minimise a screen flow and allowing them to have the flow window opened while they gather data

Tags: lightning-web-components, screen-flow, formatting, utility-bar

I have a screen flow that users want be able to minimise and have opened while they are working on gathering data for a Case. Once they use this flow to refer it on a specific case, they should not be able to use the flow again. They can only mark the record that way once.

I have looked into utility bar, but that shows for users at all times and I need it to show only on Case page.

I also researched creating LWC component that would have this flow embed and provides the minimisation functionality and controls formatting/sizing etc.

Is there someone who had a similar case and can share the best suggestions? With at least amount of code... I don't have experience with creating LWC and any help would be great.

Comment: You'll need a custom component that wraps the flow in an [expandable section](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/expandable-section/). This component can be configured with the flow name and required input variables and must be exposed so you can drop it in the case lightning record page. You would sensibly allow the admin to also control if it is expanded or collapsed by default. Alternatively, just drop a flow directly a separate tab within the page.